# need to terminate the batch file by pressing any key

Tags: windows, perl, batch-processing

I have to run a batch file using perl. The batch gets started and ends with "Press any key to continue...". I want to simulate the key pressing and get the output.

in this code, the sendkey does not work and the perl command prompt still waits till I manually press any key.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::GuiTest qw(:ALL);

my @args = ('C:\Upgrade.bat');
system(@args);
sendkey("{ENT}");`
```

Comment: you're not sending the keystroke to the batch file you executed. perl gets suspended while the system() call is working, and since your external app is sitting waiting for input, sendkey will never execute anyways. you need to `open(FH, "|externalapp"); print FH "\n"` or something.